# Magento2.2: attribute 'role': The attribute 'role' is not allowed

Tags: magento2.2

After upgrade from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.2.2

```
Element 'container', attribute 'role': The attribute 'role' is not allowed.
Line: 31
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><handle id="handle"><container name="root">
   <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
   <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
      <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
      <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
         <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
         <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
            <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
         </container>
      </container>
      <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
      <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
   </container>
</container>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="category.product.list.additional" before="-"/>
<update handle="empty"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
   <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
   <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
   <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
</referenceContainer>
<move element="catalog.leftnav" destination="content.top" after="-"/>
<update handle="empty"/>
<container name="root">
   <container name="after.body.start" as="after.body.start" before="-" label="Page Top"/>
   <container name="page.wrapper" as="page_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-wrapper">
      <container name="global.notices" as="global_notices" before="-"/>
      <container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main container">
         <container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>
         <container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns layout layout-1-col row">
            <container role="main" name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-main col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" after="-"/>
         </container>
      </container>
      <container name="page.bottom.container" as="page_bottom_container" label="Before Page Footer Container" after="main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-bottom"/>
      <container name="before.body.end" as="before_body_end" after="-" label="Page Bottom"/>
   </container>
</container>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
   <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="header-container" before="main.content"/>
   <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
   <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
</referenceContainer>
</handle></layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only just have to edit line 31

From

`<container role="main" name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-main col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" after="-"/>`

To

`<container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="col-main col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" after="-"/>`