# How to fix blog page issue in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error, blog

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'role': The attribute 'role' is not allowed.
Line: 112

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'role': The attribute 'role' is not allowed.
Line: 112

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:494]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:470]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Layout/Reader.php:93]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Layout\Reader->read() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:67]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->readPageLayout() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:54]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:212]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:225]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:170]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php:114]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout() called at [app/code/Themevast/Blog/Controller/Index/Index.php:9]
#18 Themevast\Blog\Controller\Index\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#20 Themevast\Blog\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#21 Themevast\Blog\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#22 Themevast\Blog\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Themevast/Blog/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#23 Themevast\Blog\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#28 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#30 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

Comment: please explain How and Where you got this exception

Comment: have you upgrade version?

Comment: maybe it will help you
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208994/magento2-2-attribute-role-the-attribute-role-is-not-allowed

Comment: https://www.agritura.com/it/blog